# Make Payment conversation

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have built an agent in google dialogflow cx and mostly it follows question and answer pattern. I have one use case where user would say something that initiates Make Payment Route which is an intent. When this intent is invoked I would like to implement a payment flow but don't want to configure anything on the google console. I want to control the flow through an API call, validate data, get customized text from the API. So, I would like to store user entries for each step in the flow and pass it to the next step in the flow. How can I achieve this without configuring a flow on the Google Console.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To connect with the api and process in the backend you can consider using webhook.Can you take a look at these [link1](https://medium.com/google-cloud/maximizing-your-chatbot-experience-a-step-by-step-guide-to-adding-dynamic-responses-with-af5741b3defb) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/prebuilt-component/make-a-payment).